# Paper-tabs slider move on hover

Tags: polymer

Just started building a simple website using Polymer and I can say that's not so difficult, however I want to make some thing that I haven't found in docs.

I have a simple web-app with such html structure:

```
<body class="fullbleed vertical layout">
       <paper-toolbar>
            <paper-tabs>
                <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>TAB 4</paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>
    </paper-toolbar>
</body>
```

When I click the tab for the first time the slider is shown, and then when I choose another one, it slides directly under selected tab.

But how can I refer to this behavior in my html file. I want to slide this slider, when I hover any tab. And on unhover efect return slider to current tab.

Can I do it using css only or must I use javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend that you don't actually use a hover event to perform this task purely because this sounds like a good way to destroy any form of user experience. Though, to answer your question, you can do the following:

```
<paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[someArrayOfTabs]]">
    <paper-tab on-mouseover="_handleMouseover">Tab <span>[[item.index]]</span></paper-tab>
  </template>
</paper-tabs>
```

And then in your Polymer script:

```
_handleMouseover: function(e) {
  this.selected = e.model.index;
}
```